# React + TypeScript broke overnight - "All declarations of 'value' must have identical modifiers." in node_modules/@types/es6-shim/index.d.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The error message references

```
interface IteratorResult<T> {
done: boolean;
value?: T;
}
```

in index.d.ts. I'm new to TypeScript and I can't really understand what's going on. I tried setting`"lib": ["es6", "dom"],` in tsconfig, I tried reverting to earlier Types, to no avail. Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it looks like `@types/es6-shim` is incompatible with the `lib` setting of `es6` or newer.  Please [file an issue against DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/); you can cite [this previous comment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15278#issuecomment-288475267).

In the meantime, if you can uninstall `@types/es6-shim`, that would be the easiest solution.  If you need some of the declarations from `@types/es6-shim`, you'll need to uninstall the package, add a copy of its `index.d.ts` file to your project, and delete the declarations that are causing problems.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I’ll try to hack around this in the morning. This is a job application homework task that I’ll have to finish as soon as possible so you can imagine how frustrating this is :) I’ll also file an issue.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt suggested, removing @types/es6-shim solved the problem.